# How to avoid statsmodels installation errors on windows ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

It has been a few days I've been searching a way to install statsmodel. 
I want to use ggplot library.

It dependencies are stated in the [web site](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/install.html);

1. matplotlib
2. pandas
3. scipy
4. numpy
5. statsmodels

matplotlib, pandas, scipy and numpy are successfully installed in my computer.

Then I type `pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels` on command prompt and after a while I get the following **error**;

*Exception: Cython-generated file 'statsmodels/nonparametric/linbin.c' not found. Cython is required to compile statsmodels from a development branch. Please install Cython or download a source release of statsmodels.*

**I've installed the cython using pip with the following command;**

```
pip install cython
```

I've tried installing and once again and I get the same error. 
Then I've cloned the source code to my computer from github with the following command;

```
git clone git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git
```

**I've navigated to the installation path and tried installing from setup.py file;**

```
python setup.py install
```

From this installation I get the following error ;

*File "C:\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 330: character maps to*

Does anyone have an idea to over come this problem ?

Python Version : **3.5.2**

matplotlib version : **2.0.2**

scipy version : **1.0.0**

numpy version : **1.14.0**

pandas version : **0.22.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed statsmodels from the page "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" : www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs in windows 10.